# Can not to import SpringBoot Project into Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven, spring-initializr

I have tried to create a new **SpringBoot Project** by using the **Spring Initializr**. I choose Java version (language as well), Spring Boot version and all required dependencies. Download the zip file (and unzip it), and after that I ask IDE (I use **Eclipse IDE**) to import this project, but *my IDE does not find the project file*. Below I will attach image, perhaps it will help you. If you ever met this problem, share your knowledge please)

[image: It is me IDE]

Comment: Is there a `pom.xml` file in the directory you want to import? Do you have the latest version of Eclipse and STS4? The best way to open a directory as a project is _File > Open Projects from File System..._

Comment: Of course it is. I have checked pom.xml existence.But thanks for the advice! Buy the way, it works!

Comment: It worked via _File > Open Projects from File System..._ or what was the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if Maven is installed and configured correctly on the installation path in the **Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations** tab.

[image: Maven Installation path configured properly]

Also please try if you can import the project either as a Maven project:

[image]

If not please try to import the project as a file system as below and see if it succeeds,

[image]

Comment: I do as you asked. Maven seems installed and configured correctly. Buy the way, I can imoprt either project as a Maven project. But in this case it does not work. However Thaks a lot) Importing as a system file is working correctly.